# Cannot enable Full-Text search on Azure SQL Database V12

Tags: sql-server, azure, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to enable Full-Text search on my Azure SQL Database. I upgraded my DB to V12 Standard instance. The upgrade has got completed successfully. I say that because the Status says "Online" on the portal. However, when I execute this command below,

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftCatalog AS DEFAULT;
```

it throws an error saying,

```
Msg 9972, Level 16, State 100, Line 2 
Database is not fully started up or it is not in an ONLINE state. Try the full-text DDL command again after database is started up and becomes ONLINE.
```

I am following this blog [post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/30/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/)

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Executing the below two statements by connecting to the database as well fixes this if in case you want to avoid the round trip of communicating to MSFT.

```
 Alter database [dbname] set read_committed_snapshot off with rollback immediate
Alter database [dbname] set read_committed_snapshot on with rollback immediate
```

Comment: Thanks, this error happened for us on a dev server running SQL 2012.  I toggled the value for read_committed_snapshot and then reset it to its original state, just like you wrote, and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that. We have fix for this in our deployment pipeline along with the XML doc support. So that you don't need to worry about this step. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me after an upgrade to v12 of Sql on Azure.  I did have to do rollback immediate (2 words) rather than rollback_immediate.  Also, for some reason, it hated the go statements, as well.

Comment: Update: This issue is fixed world wide and this shouldn't surface anymore.

Comment: @Satya_MSFT I'm having this issue in a 2019 AG group right now.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the question. The error you are experiencing is related to an internal issue that we are aware of and currently in the process of fixing.  To mitigate your issue, could you please email me at joseidz at microsoft dot com with server and database name and we will get this fixed for you.