# After Upgrading databases to Azure SQL V12 and enabling Full-Text Search, issues with importing and exporting bacpac files using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

recently we updated our SQL Azure Servers and Databases to V12 in order to utilize the Full-Text Search functionality. This worked well after running a few statements found here in this post [Cannot enable Full-Text search on Azure SQL Database V12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759967/cannot-enable-full-text-search-on-azure-sql-database-v12/)

However after enabling Full-Text Search in the DB, we are now unable to export the data-tier application to bacpac file using SSMS. We are running into this error:

The element ft is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

I'm on SQL Server 2014 Management Studio SP1 with CU1 - (this is the latest I believe)

I found a similar issue here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6f3feaa-a671-4618-abda-584b923fb2a8/error-exporting-databaseindexing-for-document-type-doc-is-not-supported-on-microsoft-azure-sql?forum=ssdt/ that suggests using SqlPackage.exe to export VS going through the wizard, however the error is not exactly the same and I'm not sure if that would work.

On a related note, exporting the database to a bacpac file through the Azure Preview Portal (portal.azure.com) was relatively simple and did work as long as you have blob storage setup, I would like to continue to use and work with SSMS 2014 though.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the following hotfix for it to work:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=3058512&kbln=en-us

Comment: I have SQL Server 2014 SP1 with CU1

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3067839/

My understanding is that 2014 SP1 with CU1 is the equivalent to 2014 RTM with CU6.

Answer (score 1):

Export in SSMS is powered by the Data Tier Application Framework, otherwise known as DacFX. Updates for DacFX can be downloaded and installed separately from the SSMS installer. The latest version of DacFX adds support for FTS on Azure V12. Look here for the DacFX download: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/05/18/sql-server-data-tools-update-for-may-2015.aspx

Once installed, SSMS 2014 will use the newer version.

Comment: This worked. I had previously tried to install the DacFX files, I guess they were the wrong version. To get this to work I did the following:

1. Install SQL Server 2014 SP1 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46694/
2. Install SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU1 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3067839/
3. Install SSDT for Visual Studio 2013 (not sure if necessary...) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn864412/
4. Install the latest DacFX files x86 AND x64 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898/

Thank you!!